# Unable to cast TokenCloudCredentials to AccessTokenCredential when calling New-AzureRmADApplication

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, service-principal

I'm writing a PowerShell deployment script which automates the creation of my Azure resources and an accompanying ServicePrincipal.

Here is the code I'm using, which I've tested and works when run directly from PowerShell with the latest Azure 1.0.4 SDK module:

```
$ResourceGroupName = "my-resource-group"
$ADAppIdentifierUri = [string]::Concat("https://", $ResourceGroupName, ".azurewebsites.net")

# Generate a password for the AD application
$ServicePrincipalPassword = [Guid]::NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "")

# Create the Azure AD Application and service principal, and only assign access to our resource group
$AzureADApplication = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName $ResourceGroupName -HomePage $ADAppIdentifierUri -IdentifierUris $ADAppIdentifierUri -Password $ServicePrincipalPassword
```

When I run this code using my ResourceGroup project deployment script in Visual Studio, I get the following error:

> New-AzureRmADApplication : Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Azure.TokenCloudCredentials' to type 'Microsoft.Azure.Common.Authentication.AccessTokenCredential'.

According to the stack trace the exception was raised at the start of the command New-AzureRmADApplication, so the exception is happening internally in the Azure SDK code unfortunately.

I've browsed the source code of the SDK in the following files and could not find any insight:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/f803b991daa7eeeea1217238ab071c8d83de34be/src/ResourceManager/Resources/Commands.Resources/ActiveDirectory/NewAzureADApplicationCommand.cs

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/956d0ca795acfce67d8f142bf059ab2b8ab2c67b/src/ResourceManager/Resources/Commands.Resources/Models.ActiveDirectory/ActiveDirectoryClient.cs

https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/Microsoft.Azure.Graph.RBAC/1.6.0-preview/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0/Microsoft.Azure.Graph.RBAC/Microsoft.Azure.Graph.RBAC/Generated/GraphRbacManagementClient.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.Azure.Graph.RBAC

I can only find one person who's encountered this same error at this link here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/

However, the solution there does not make sense to me because I am not using a management certificate to authenticate, and I don't have any management certificates listed on the manage.windowsazure.com site.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? I copy your code and run with a `Login-AzureRmAccount`, and it works perfectly for me. I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and Azure PowerShell 1.2.1

Comment: I'm using the same, Visual Studio 2015 with Azure PowerShell - February 2016 (1.2.1).

Comment: What kind of login strategy do you use? The Visual Studio Automatically generated script use `Microsoft.Azure.Common.Authentication.AzureSession`, and the script uses Azure PowerShell 0.9 style commands, which is not working with Azure PowerShell 1.2.1. I am trying to figure out how to make use of the Azure Session of Visual Studio to login. It would be very helpful if you share your code.

Comment: I'm using the boilerplate *Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1* script that comes with the project template Cloud -> Resource Group.  I'm running the script by using the actual Deploy option of the project file.  The snippet of code I linked above can be placed in this file to test the circumstances.

Comment: By using the Get-AzureRmContext cmdlet I've been able to determine that when running Azure PowerShell in Visual Studio the authentication for the account is done using an AccessToken.  However when I authenticate with Login-AzureRmAccount in PowerShell it does not use such a token.  I'm guessing this is causing the underlying problem.

Comment: I tried that too, and found out that the ASM commands are good to use. I tried `Get-AzureAccount`, and it returned my visual studio account with Type "AccessTaken", which means it login ASM correctly. However, `Get-AzureRmContext` always runs with error. And, I don't think using a simple `Login-AzureRmAccount` is the correct way to login in this case, because you might log into a different account. There should be another way to make ARM work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue (i.e. bug) when using token based authentication with the AzureRMAD* cmdlets.  When you run the script from VS, VS uses the token you have from the VS sign-in to avoid prompting for auth.  To work around it, you have to run it outside of VS using credentials.

There is an internal work item tracking this but if you want to monitor progress you can file an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/

Comment: Yeah I figured as much, I went with the approach of calling a deployment script manually from PowerShell and everything is working now.

Comment: I've added the issue as suggested https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/2273